# RequestStateForRegion after startMonitoringForRegion in Swift

Tags: swift2, cllocationmanager

When I start monitoring a region like

```
locationManager.startMonitoringForRegion(tGeoFence[wert][wert2])
```

and try to determine if it is already entered right after that like this:

```
for region in locationManager.monitoredRegions {
    if let cireg = region as? CLCircularRegion {
        if cireg.identifier == tGeoFence[wert][wert2].identifier {
            locationManager.requestStateForRegion(cireg)
        }
    }
}
```

doesn't work, cause the registration of the region is not finished when the 2nd part of the code is executed. Delaying the execution of that part seems ugly ([diddeterminestate not always called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24543814/diddeterminestate-not-always-called)), is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 6):

Found out, obviously the **didStartMonitoringForRegion** delegate function is the right place to ask for **requestStateForRegion**:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringForRegion region: CLRegion) {
    locationManager.requestStateForRegion(region)   
}
```

**Edit:** Awful thing is, I still need a short delay or sometimes **requestStateForRegion** is not called:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didStartMonitoringForRegion region: CLRegion) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(0.1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.locationManager.requestStateForRegion(region)
    }
}
```

: (