# didDetermineStateForRegion not fired when restarting bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ibeacon, android-ibeacon

I'm trying to fix a bug that occurs when, running my app (ionic 4) on an android device and monitoring for beacons regions i turn off the device bluetooth and then turn it on again.

This the process:

- run my app with bluetooth on
- startMonitoringForRegion
- didDetermineStateForRegion --> works
- Turn Off device bluetooth
- stopMonitoringForRegion
- Turn On device bluetooth
- didDetermineStateForRegion is not fired

**IMPORTANT** --> Ugly solution with **setTimeout** --> **SOLVE THE ISSUE**
--> [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25211343/4197536) a stackoverflow with this workaround.

---------- HERE MY BEACONS OBJECT

```
this.beaconsFromJson = [
  {
    identifier: 'Mini S/N 018727',
    uuid: 'my-beacon-uuid',
    major: 1,
    minor: 18727,
    notifyEntryStateOnDisplay: false
  },
  {
    identifier: 'Mini S/N 018730',
    uuid: 'my-beacon-uuid',
    major: 1,
    minor: 18730,
    notifyEntryStateOnDisplay: false
  }
];
```

---------- HERE MY SCAN FUNCTION

```
scan() {

_.forEach( this.beaconsFromJson, beacon => {

  const beaconRegion = this.ibeacon.BeaconRegion(
    beacon.identifier,
    beacon.uuid,
    beacon.major,
    beacon.minor,
    beacon.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay
  )

  this.ibeacon.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion).then(
    () => console.log('Start monitoring' + beaconRegion.identifier),
    (error) =>
      console.error('Native layer failed to begin monitoring: ', error)
  );

}) // end foreach

setTimeout( () => {
  this.delegate.didDetermineStateForRegion().subscribe((data: IBeaconPluginResult) => {
    switch (data.state) {
      case 'CLRegionStateInside':
        this.beacons.push(data.region);
        this.loadingService.loading$.next({status: false});
        break;
      case 'CLRegionStateOutside':
        this.loadingService.loading$.next({status: false});
        this.beacons = this.beacons.filter(beacon => beacon.identifier !== data.region.identifier);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  })
}, 1); // Ugly but it works --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/25211343/4197536
}
```

- When i start my app with bluetooth OFF and then i turn it ON -> It
  works as expected.
- When i start my app with bluetooth ON and then i turn it OFF and ON
  again --> Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined (that
  subscription i do to didDetermineStateForRegion())

Nb: This script works, but i'm looking for a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

The question describes this sequence:

- stopMonitoringForRegion
- Turn On device bluetooth
- didDetermineStateForRegion is not fired

The last bullet point is expected because monitoring was stopped in the first bullet point.  In order to get a `didDetermineStateForRegion` callback, monitoring must be started.